# Can not see Solidity events

Tags: solidity, web3js, events

I can see events in a private net, but when I connect to "real" net, I can not see them. Meaning `.watch(function(err, result)` is never called. 
My theory is I am using lightning, and it probably means events are not loaded.

Am I correct?
What else can it be?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is correct, please tell me if I am wrong, but as you are running a ligth node, you migth follow this step if you have not done it yet:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol#principles

> Light clients want to "watch" for events that are logged. The protocol
>   here is the following: A light client gets all block headers, checks
>   for block headers that contain bloom filters that match one of a
>   desired list of addresses or topics that the light client is
>   interested in Upon finding a potentially matching block header, the
>   light client downloads all transaction receipts, checks them for
>   transactions whose bloom filters match Upon finding a potentially
>   matching transaction, the light client checks its actual log RLP, and
>   sees if it actually matches